# Python replace oneliner without using regexp

Tags: python

I have my code here:

```
a = u"\n".join(my_array).replace(u"\n\n", u"\n")
```

The problem is that if there are `"\n\n\n\n"` you are left with `"\n\n"` and I just want **one** `"\n"`

So I've come up with:

```
a = u"\n".join(my_array)
while a.find(u"\n\n")>=0:
    a = a.replace(u"\n\n", u"\n")
```

I was wondering if there's a more elegant way / maybe oneliner *without using regexp* to do this in Python?

Comment: @DeepakKamat: I get the feeling that the OP would like to avoid doing multiple loops over the input string...

Comment: Why not use regex? Also, usually the answer to "one-liner questions" is: Write a function.

Comment: Also, why do you remove duplicate `\n` after joining by `\n`? Wouldn't it be easier to strip `\n` before `joining? Can there be `\n\n` inside the strings in `my_array`? You should show some input data and expected output.

Comment: From the use of `u"..."` I assume that you're using Python 2. Is that correct?

Comment: You have two strange restrictions: a onliner, and no regexp. In real code these are silly restrictions. Is this a homework assignment?

Comment: Watch my profile, I'm a teacher myself... I just hate regexp because you almost *always* end up with complex (= hard to maintain) regexp, that's why I just want to avoid them. It's like drug: you begin small, then end up with huge and unreadable regexp. Believe elder people!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you really want to do this in one line and without using regular expression, one way to reduce all the sequences of multiple `\n` to single `\n` would to be first `split` by `\n` and then `join` all the non-empty segments by a single `\n`.

```
>>> a = "foo\n\nbar\n\n\nblub\n\n\n\nbaz"
>>> "\n".join(x for x in a.split("\n") if x)
'foo\nbar\nblub\nbaz'
```

Here, `a` is the *entire* string, i.e. after you did `"\n".join(my_array)`, and depending on what `my_array` originally is, there may be better solutions, e.g. stripping `\n` from the individual lines prior to joining, but this will work nonetheless.

Comment: I love it I'll try and validate if it's ok

Answer (score 2):

To convert sequences of newlines to single newlines you can split the string on newlines and then filter out the empty strings before re-joining. Eg,

```
mystring = u"this\n\nis a\ntest string\n\nwith embedded\n\n\nnewlines\n"
a = u'\n'.join(filter(None, mystring.split(u'\n')))
print '{0!r}\n{1!r}'.format(mystring, a)
```

**output**

```
u'this\n\nis a\ntest string\n\nwith embedded\n\n\nnewlines\n'
u'this\nis a\ntest string\nwith embedded\nnewlines'
```

Note that this eliminates any trailing newlines, but that shouldn't be a big deal.

Comment: looks pretty good. One thing: input in OP is array, not string.

Comment: @ailin: Sure. I was just showing how to clean things up _after_ the list of strings has already been joined into a single string. The OP didn't supply a sample list of strings, and I'd prefer not to speculate about the exact format of its strings since (as already mentioned) there may be a more efficient strategy if the strings in the input list don't contain embedded newlines.

Answer (score 1):

Using `reduce` should work:

```
reduce(lambda x,y: (x+y).replace('\n\n', '\n'), x)
```

However, regular expressions would be more elegant:

```
re.sub('\n+', '\n', x)
```

Answer (score 0):

perhaps this can help:

```
u"\n".join(s.replace(u'\n', '') for s in my_array))
```

Comment: Maybe, unless some of the strings in `my_array` contain embedded newlines, i.e., ones that aren't at the end of the string.